# How to fix Docker error `Set environment variable LICENSE=accept`

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-registry, docker-machine

I am getting this error when starting docker:

```
Set environment variable LICENSE=accept to indicate acceptance of license terms
and conditions.

License agreements and information can be viewed by running this image with the
environment variable LICENSE=view.  You can also set the LANG environment variab
le to view the license in a different language.
```

[image: Docker startup error]

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Going to take a massive shot in the dark here and assume you've downloaded an image with some licensed software that requires you to accept it before using. If you're trying to do this with docker, you'll probably need:

```
docker run <some...args> -e LICENSE=accept <image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accept the license agreement on Docker Desktop by, similarly to the command line solution, creating the Environment Variable "LICENSE" with the value "accept" when running the container from the downloaded image. You can do this under optional settings when you run a new container from the image.